Why doesn't JPA Query cast enum automatically?
This is my entity (mapping to Postgres)
@Entity
@Table(name = "price_project")
class PriceProject(
    @Column val priceEur: Double,
    @Column(name = "valid_from", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    val validFrom: ZonedDateTime?,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column val projectType: ProjectTypes
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0
}

This is the enum ProjectTypes
@EnumNaming(EnumNamingStrategies.CamelCaseStrategy::class)
enum class ProjectTypes {
    national,
    international,
    trans_national,
    global,
}

And this is the CREATE statement for the table price_project with the enum project_type.
CREATE TABLE public.price_project (
    id bigint NOT NULL,                                                   
    price double precision,
    project_type public.project_types NOT NULL,
    valid_from timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TYPE public.project_types AS ENUM (
    'national',
    'international',
    'trans_national',
    'global',
);

Now, I am trying to create a query with the enum ProjectTypes
interface ProjectPriceRepository : JpaRepository<ProjectPrice, Long> {
    @Query("""
        SELECT p FROM PriceProject p
        WHERE p.validFrom <= :currentDate AND
        p.activityType = :projectType 
        """)
    fun findProject(
        @Param("projectType") projectType: ProjectTypes,
        @Param("validFrom") currentDate: ZonedDateTime,
    ): PriceProject?
}

But this gives me

JDBC exception executing SQL [select ... from price_project where ... project_type=? [ERROR: operator does not exist: project_type = character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 386] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]

Why doesn't JPA not type cast automatically?
I am trying with a native query
    @Query("""
        SELECT * FROM project_price p
        valid_from <= :currentDate AND
        activity_type = CAST(:projectType AS project_type)
        """,
        nativeQuery = true)

But this gives me

[ERROR: cannot cast type smallint to project_type]


It does convert and does exactly as you told it to. It converts it to a varchar (that is what EnumType.STRING is) however in the database it isn't a varchar but an enum .

@M.Deinum, well, what is the solution to this?

@M.Deinum This is possible to achieve, I have this running. I cannot tell the issue here, though. Might be a DB version feature issue.

You would need to provide additional information (metadata) to JPA to convert it to a PostgreSQL enum (assuming Postgres here).

This article might help : https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

@M.Deinum I edited my Q. This is what I have tried with native query but no luck..

The solution to this is
@JdbcType(PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType::class) // org-hibernate-orm:hibernate-core
@Enumerated
@Column(columnDefinition = "project_types") // make sure this is the exact name of the type in postgres
val projectType: ProjectTypes

which makes this one
interface ProjectPriceRepository : JpaRepository<ProjectPrice, Long> {
    @Query("""
        SELECT p FROM PriceProject p
        WHERE p.validFrom <= :currentDate AND
        p.activityType = :projectType 
        """)
    fun findProject(
        @Param("projectType") projectType: ProjectTypes,
        @Param("validFrom") currentDate: ZonedDateTime,
    ): PriceProject?
}

work.
If you have an array of enum types in Postgres, you need to do the following
@Type(
    value = EnumArrayType::class,
    parameters = [Parameter(name = AbstractArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE, value = "project_types")]
) // this tells hibernate what type the elements have in the array, thus project_types without []!
@Column(columnDefinition = "project_types[]") val projectTypes: Array<ProjectTypes>  // note the [] here. Also, you have to use an array. A list won't work!

You also need an additional dependency
implementation("io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63:3.7.0")

The most recent version of Spring Boot won't work with it. There is a bug. Downgrade to org.springframework.boot version "3.2.0".

Depending on your actual JDBC driver's implementation, and your ORM mapper (e.g. hibernate), it is required to add additional information to the entity class in order to resolve the enum type.
Blindly assuming you are using POSTGRES and hibernate you might need:
@JdbcType(PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType::class) // org-hibernate-orm:hibernate-core
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "project_type", columnDefinition = "public.project_types")
val projectType: ProjectTypes

for the mapper to be able to simply put your enum into the query as string (why this has to be so complicated, I have no idea).
As for the
@EnumNaming(EnumNamingStrategies.CamelCaseStrategy::class)
enum class ProjectTypes { ...

I am not certain, if this does not conflict with your database definition of the enum, as enums in most SQL languages are not case sensitive, and your specific definition is snake case.

When I try to add your suggestions, I am getting Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [project_type] in table [project_price]; found [project_type (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [projectTypes (Types#NAMED_ENUM)]. Oh and yes, I am using postgres.

I am unsure which side is which, whether the jpa side inserts varchar, or the DB holds varchar. Can you make sure the table is actually set to an enum?

The table is definetly set to an enum. I just triple checked.

can you try to add @Column(name = "project_type", columnDefinition = "public.project_types") instead of the parameter free @Column? (I am guessing at this point)

Same error... If I remove the @JdbcType(PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType::class) it compiles. But I cannot run the query. Same error with the query. I mean, I could write a raw query and cast in the raw query. But I fell like this is sth JPA should do for me?

I have the following working with postgres and hibernate-core 6.4.4.Final: @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)     @Column(name = "my_column", columnDefinition = "schema.type_name")     @JdbcType(PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType::class)     var myColumn: TypeName
Maybe try to remove the @EnumNaming(EnumNamingStrategies.CamelCaseStrategy::class)?
I can only guess at a bug in either the postgres version, the hibernate version or jdbc driver...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Found the solution, posted it as an answere here.
